# Limit information given out with Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to limit what information is shared via Facebook connect?

I really like the service, but I don't like how you have to accept it on the respective websites' terms. Is there any way to create different profiles for different sites?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to limit the information passed.  Other than not having it on your profile. As a developer I have coded for Facebook connect. The information is not always used for example we use email first-name and surname just for login purposes.